# How do I copy style from one button to another?

Tags: javascript

**My goal:**

I am trying to replace the button on a screen using Javascript.

I need the buttons to look the same, so I am trying to copy the style from the old button to the new button.

**The problem:**

The button styling is not being reflected on the `newButton` (either because I am not getting it properly from `oldButton`, or because I am not applying it to `newButton` properly)

**Here is my code:**

```
oldButtonStyle = window.getComputedStyle(oldButton).cssText;

newButton = document.createElement("INPUT");
newButton.style.cssText = oldButtonStyle;

oldButton.parentNode.replaceChild(
  newButton,
  oldButton
);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ - Maybe, but first... Why? Why do replace a "button" with a text input? What do you try to accomplish with that?

Comment: just add the same class to the new button...

Answer (score 2):

First get the element style with `style.cssText`

Then use `setAttribute()` to set the style.

Here in the snippet below you can set the style on the button with id `btn2` when you click on it.

```js
const style = document.getElementById("btn1").style.cssText;

function setStyle() {
  document.getElementById("btn2").setAttribute('style', style); 
}
```

```html
<button style="color: red;background-color: yellow" id="btn1">button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="setStyle()">button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but based on "I need the buttons to look the same, so I am trying to copy the style from the old button to the new button.",

Here is a simple solution

```js
// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");

const oldButton = document.getElementById('button');
const oldButtonStyle = window.getComputedStyle(
  document.getElementById('button1'),
  "" // optional for pulling styles from pseudo selectors :before, :after
).cssText;

const newButton = document.createElement("INPUT");
newButton.style.cssText = oldButtonStyle;

oldButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newButton, oldButton);
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

#button {
  height: 64px;
  border: red;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#button1 {
  height: 64px;
  border: red;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button id="button">Old</button>
  <button id="button1">Another Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the `, "")` do? Why did you add `#button1` and what does this change?

Comment: `, "")` is an optional argument, used for pulling styles from pseudo selectors `:before`, `:after`. `#button1` is just to show that the styles indeed do get copied. (Note: Background color property in CSS)

Answer (score 1):

```
Just use that old button color specification by using DOM in app.js file

    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn" type="button" style="background-color: 
         green;cursor: pointer;">Click Me!</button>
        <script src='./app.js'></script>
    </body>


// create app.js file and clone the color by using id and create a new button tag and link whatever you provide specification to them and in lastjust append it

const colorElement = document.getElementById('btn').style.backgroundColor;

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Click me");
    x.style.backgroundColor = colorElement
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```